# How do I scrape specific app details in the App Store?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, app-store

I'm trying to bring up a web scraping solution to gather various app details given the apps' bundle IDs, then parse the JSON string for specific parameters like version and price. I'm building this up separately and will eventually merge it into my main solution.

So far, I've gotten it to work with scraping details for Android apps, here's what I have so far for Android apps.

```
# NOTE: I'm running this in Google Colab, hence why I'm running "pip install" commands alongside the code
!pip install google-play-scraper

from google_play_scraper import app

bundleID = 'com.n3twork.tetris'
result = app(bundleID)
version = result['version']
price = result['price']
print("\nVersion:", version)
print("  Price:", price)
```

Which outputs the following.

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: google-play-scraper in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.2.0)

Version: 5.0.3
  Price: 0
```

However, I haven't had the same luck with iOS scraping. The closest I got was for it to output a bunch of links, and a JSON string. In the end, I want to input a bundle ID, like `com.n3twork.tetris` and get its `version` and `price`, and/or any other parameters collected in the JSON string. Here are couple sources I'm referencing.

- [1] https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper
- [2] https://pypi.org/project/itunes-app-scraper-dmi/#description

I tried running the code in [2], preceded by `!pip install itunes-app-scraper-dmi` (Running in Colab). For reference, here's the code.

```
!pip install itunes-app-scraper-dmi

from itunes_app_scraper.scraper import AppStoreScraper
import json

scraper = AppStoreScraper()
results = scraper.get_app_ids_for_query("minecraft")
similar = scraper.get_similar_app_ids_for_app(results[0])

app_details = scraper.get_multiple_app_details(similar)
#version = app_details['version']
print(list(app_details))
```

This outputs a bunch of links which download `1.txt` when clicking them, and a long JSON string containing all of the app details. The output is lengthy, so I've shortened it for this post.

```
# Output too long, more details BEFORE this

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=824305459&country=nl&entity=software
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1072395467&country=nl&entity=software
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1319618742&country=nl&entity=software
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1596871014&country=nl&entity=software
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=575154654&country=nl&entity=software
[{'isGameCenterEnabled': False, 'advisories': 'Regelmatig/Intens animatiegeweld of fictief geweld,Regelmatig/Intense horror-/angstthema’s', 'supportedDevices': 'iPhone5s-iPhone5s 

# Output too long, more details AFTER this
```

How do I run this so that I can input a bundle ID (e.g. `com.n3twork.tetris`) parse the details I'm interested in (`version`, `price`) and store them in respective variables to be used throughout the rest of the code? **Similar to how I did for Android apps (above).**

How do I debug this and get the info I'm interested in? Am I in the right direction? Or is there a better solution for iOS web scraping?